# Unable to Extract value from JSON response which has the data in "\"

Tags: json, jmeter

Please help me to get out the problem which I am facing. I have a JSON response like this:

"{"Version":10,"Collections":[{"Id":"************","Name":"*****","Description":null,"IsValid":false,"ABC":"\\XYZ\\collection\\","C

and want to fetch the values of collections which has n number of Id's but JSON extractor is not working here.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample JSON response? Ideally, the JSON should be validated before posting. Also, you shall nicely format the JSON in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) otherwise even those who are willing to help won't re-type your code or use OCR software in order to reproduce your issue
2. What you're showing to us is not a valid JSON, you can check it yourself using an offline or online [JSON Lint Tool](https://jsonlint.com/) hence you won't be able to use JSON Extractor for this.

If you get escaped JSON as a part of some JSON attribute, like this one:

```
{
  "some-attribute": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}
```

You won't be get this `bar` value directly so you will need to do this in 2 steps:

1. Use 1st JSON Extractor to get the value of `some-attribute`
2. Use 2nd JSON Extractor to get the value of `foo` attribute

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dmitri. Will take care henceforth. with due respect, i tried ur suggestion but no luck: Collections=NOT FOUND
Collections_matchNr=0
Id=NOT FOUND
Id_matchNr=0

Comment: "{\"Version\":10,\"Collections\":[{\"Id\":\"************\",\"Name\":\"*****\",\"Description\":null,\"IsValid\":false,\"ABC\":\"\\\\XYZ\\\\collection\\\\\",\"C----like this, i have the JSON

Comment: It's not "the JSON", JSON starts from `{` or `[`.

Comment: The site u referred to me is saying "Valid JSON"

Comment: It is working. Using Regular Expression Extractor PostProcessor to get id value like this:                    
 "Id.":."(.+?).",."Name                                                                                                                                              Thanks for help!